# Passing json from javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, api

I am using the google maps API to do some distance calculations and want to pass an array from  JS to a completely different PHP page. I thought I had done is correctly by outputting a json string to the html body with JS on page output.php, then on the other page php page (retrieve.php) using cURL to get the page contents. But this retrieves the whole contents of the HTML page, including the javascript, html tags etc. I just want to be able to retrieve a json string from a page generated by JS and using this json in the PHP on a different page. What is the best method to do this?

Thanks

js code trying to output json:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            window.onload = function() {
                var myObj = {
                    1: 1,
                    2: 2,
                    3: 4,
                    4: 3
                };
                document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(myObj);
            }

        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP file:

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_URL,'http://localhost:81/output.php');
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);                                                                 
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);                                                                      
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: application/json')                                                                       
);      
$content = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);

$array = json_decode($content);
print_r($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript, running on the client, is not going to be able to output data *to the page* in a fashion that *a different request* for the page is going to be able to read. It can only modify the in-memory *copy* of the page.

Serialise the data to a query string and go to the other PHP page by `location = other_php_url + query_string`, then read the data from `$_GET` instead of using `cURL`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with an ajax call, like the following (this is using jQuery):

```
my_json_data = {"my_data": "blabla"};
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://www.mywebsite.com/my_php_script.php',
  type: "POST",
  data: my_json_data,
  success:function(data){
    alert("Data received");
  }
});
```

On the php side you should do something like this:

```
<?php //This is my_php_script.php

$my_data = $_POST["my_data"];

...
```

Comment: Is this not just getting json from a PHP file into JS? I am looking to get json from a JS to a PHP file.

Comment: No, it's the other way around... it's sending the json to a php script through the ajax call... try and see!